# How to set an instance of the EventHandler interface as the action for a button

Tags: java, button, javafx, actionevent

I am trying to set the action of a button by passing an instance of the `EventHandler<>` interface to its `setOnAction()` method, however it is not working.

**Class 1:**

```java
public class Class1 {
       
   private Class2 class2;
   private Button buttonDelete = null;

   private Button getButtonDelete() {
       if (buttonDelete == null) {
           buttonDelete = new Button("Delete");
           buttonDelete.setOnAction(class2);
       }
       return buttonDelete;
   }
}
```

**Class 2:**

```java
public class Class2 implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you _really_ trying to achieve? This sounds very much like an x-y-problem,  [mcve] please ..

Comment: You need to initialize class2:  `Class2 class2 = new Class2();`

Comment: @kleopatra I am currently looking for the error, which is why my tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() always returns null. Therefore I outsource parts of my code straight to minimize the error sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Short answer :

```
public Class1(Class2 class2){
this.class2 = class2;
}
```

To call the constructor : `new Class1(new Class2());` the handle method will be called automatically when the event triggred.

2. Long answer, using anonymous classes is better for button event handling so learn about anonymouse classes and lambda expressions, good learning.